# Saving graph with CairoPDF in a sourced R file

Tags: r, file-writing

I have a bunch of different graphs that I am trying to make, and I want to have an individual R file for each graph in addition to an R file that `source`s all of these R files.

This makes it easier to find and edit things since there is only code for one graph in each R file, but I still want to be able to make all of the graphs at once.

I thought I would be able to do this by having an R that just `source`s all of the individual R files that make the graphs.

However, executing the the `test2.R` script leads to a blank PDF file being created in `~/Documents/`, whereas uncommenting the first two lines of `test.R` and just running that R script by itself leads to the expected PDF file in `~/Documents/`.

Why is this the case? Is there a way to fix it?

### `test.R` (saved as `~/Desktop/test.R`)

```r
#library(ggplot2)
#library(Cairo)
CarPlot <- ggplot() +
    stat_summary(data = mtcars,
                 aes(x = factor(gear),
                     y = mpg,
                     fill = factor(gear)
                     ),
                 fun.y = "mean",
                 geom = "bar"
                 )
setwd("~/Documents/")
CairoPDF(file = "CarPlot.pdf")
CarPlot
dev.off()
```

### `test2.R` (saved as `~/Desktop/test2.R`)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(Cairo)
source(file = "~/Desktop/test.R")
```

Comment: Be sure to actually print the plot: `print(CarPlot)`. Plots aren't automatically drawn when running non-interactively via `source()`.

Comment: @MrFlick Hmm, adding `print(CarPlot)` to `test.R` does *not* fix the problem. However, setting `print.eval = TRUE` inside the call to `source()` does fix the problem.

Comment: That seems highly unlikely, but at least you got something that works. You did replace the `CarPlot` with `print(CarPlot`) in between the `CairoPDF()` and `dev.off()`?

Comment: @MrFlick Ah, oops. Forgot to save the change before executing the script. It does indeed work with `print()` as well. Thanks for the quick response! You can go ahead and vote to close this as a duplicate if you'd like. I appreciate it!